# Как определить вид сложного предложения и его главной части?

Tags: сложное-предложение

***Такое впечатление, что мы уже здесь были.***

1) Главное предложение вряд ли можно назвать неполным, так как, по школьному определению, "там отсутствуют формально необходимые главные или второстепенные члены, значение которых ясно из контекста или ситуации".

Примечание.

Выделяют три вида неполных предложений: контекстуально-неполные, ситуативно-неполные и диалогические неполные предложения (от слова *диалог)*.

2) Какова роль в предложении у местоимения ***такое***.

Comment: Сказуемое-то отсутствует? [Складывается] такое впечатление.

Comment: Да, сказуемого нет, но такова структура предложения. Нам не нужен контекст, чтобы восстановить его. Сказуемое  подразумевается (как, например,  в эллиптических предложениях), но грамматически оно не обозначено.

Comment: Эллиптические тоже относятся к неполным.

Comment: Разные есть классификации, некоторые считают, что это особый вид неполных предложений. Но в любом случае эллиптические предложения являются двусоставными и сказуемого не требуют (оно только подразумевается)..

Answer (score 2):

*Такое впечатление, что мы уже здесь были.*

Это  сложноподчинённое предложение  с придаточным определительным, которое присоединяется к главному с помощью **союза что**, в таком случае в главном обязательно употребляется указательное слово ТАКОЙ, при этом придаточное имеет дополнительный смысл следствия, цели, сравнения, степени. Здесь оттенок следствия.

Главное предложение имеет переходный вид. Кто-то относит его к полным двусоставным, где составное именное сказуемое ТАКОЕ с применением инверсии (*впечатление такое, что*...-  прямой порядок), кто-то говорит об эллипсисе (у меня такое впечатление, что...), а кто-то относит к **фразеологизированным предложениям - штампам**. Это предложение действительно используется часто как готовая формула (как, например, *"Что с вами?", "Как жизнь?", "Как дела?")* По крайней мере, синтаксическое членение здесь точно затруднено, оʜᴎ обладают основным признаком предложения — предикативностью, но, в отличие от свободно конструируемых предложений, обрели свойство воспроизводимости, что сближает их с фразеологическими единицами. К фразеологизированным относятся неглагольные предложения типа Счастливого пути!; Что нового? и т.п., в отличие от эллиптических, предложения-штампы утратили соотносительность с глагольными конструкциями (ср.: Как идут дела?; Что с вами происходит?).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне бы хотелось возразить по двум пунктам: а) союз ЧТО не имеет значения следствия, это изъяснительный союз; б) предложение не стоит считать фразеологической единицей, его, как я думаю,  можно включить в общую классификацию.

Answer (score 0):

Пока никто не отвечал на вопрос,  я составила свой план ответа.

Мне это предложение уже не кажется нестандартным, фразеологизованным, **и его вполне можно вписать в общую классификацию.**

1) Как известно, **связь в СПП бывает трех видов:** местоименная, союзная и местоименно-союзная (смешанная).

2) **Вот пример местоименно-определительного предложения** (связь местоименная): *Восторг на лице у девочки такой, какой бывает исключительно по поводу первой примерки нового платья*.   В местоименно-определительных придаточных  (в отличие от определительных) указательные слова  одновременно являются и определяемыми словами.

3) **А это местоименно-союзная связь:** *Конь такой, что всех потопчет. Треск такой, будто сломалось дерево.* Союзы со значением следствия и сравнения. Придаточные определительные и местоименно-определительные предложения могут иметь двойное значение определение + следствие, определение + сравнение.

4) **Заданное предложение**: *Впечатление такое, что мы уже здесь были.*

Это тоже **местоименно-союзная связь**, только союз ЧТО – изъяснительный (а не следствия или сравнения)

Итак, это СПП с **придаточным местоименно-изъяснительным**, связь местоименно-союзная, ЧТО – изъяснительный союз, указательное слово такой является **сказуемым** в главном предложении.

**Получился такой "гибрид" из местоименно-определительного и изъяснительного предложений, но с довольно простой грамматикой.**

А вот еще подобные предложения:

Может случиться такое, что все ныне известные законы физики отменятся. В общем, мораль такая, что паника вредна.

Comment: Смешно: мне Вы возразили: а) союз ЧТО не имеет значения следствия, это изъяснительный союз. Сами же пишете: "А это местоименно-союзная связь: Конь такой, что всех потопчет. ...Союзы со значением следствия и сравнения. Придаточные определительные и местоименно-определительные предложения могут иметь двойное значение определение + следствие, определение + сравнение". Вам можно такое сказать, а мне нет? А вот у Валгиной пример: Попадья взглянула на Мишку такими глазами, что ему стало страшно. Она определяет его как определительное с  доп. знач. следствия и степени.

Comment: И второе Ваше  возражение желательно объяснить, почему же главное предложение не следует считать фразеологизированной единицей. Есть много мнений в науке, много классификаций, три из них я изложила, но Вы не приняли ответ, написали свой - истину в высшей инстанции, хотя один из моих вариантов совпал с Вашим. Какой смысл задавать вопрос, если Вам не нужен ответ? Или только мой не нужен? Мне больше не отвечать? Ник Вы изменили, а отношение - нет.

Comment: Извините, но я всего лишь высказала свое мнение.  К сожалению, оно не совпадает с Вашим по двум указанным вопросам. В то же время  ваш ответ интересен другим участникам форума, и они поддержали Вас.